# Is there an integral representation for Euler's Totient function?

Tags: totient-function

The question is pretty much in the title. Euler's Totient function $\varphi(n)$ satisfy the following formula:

$$\varphi(n) =n \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

Is it possible through this formula or something else to represent $\varphi(n)$ as an integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to consider the Dirichlet series of the Euler's totient function, and arrive at an integral using the coefficient inversion formula (relevant content: sections 2 and 7 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series).

I do not know if this satisfies the conditions in the question asked (because it was slightly vague) but I hope it helps.